# Adding multiple conditions in where clause in bulk update in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, where-clause

Below code for bulk update is working where `benefits_dict` is my list of dictionaries.

```
conn.execute(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.update()
                             .where(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.c.user_id == bindparam('user_id')),
                             benefits_dict)
```

Now when I go and add multiple conditions to my where clause like below, it doesn't work.

```
conn.execute(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.update()
                             .where(MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.c.user_id == bindparam('user_id') & MedicalPlanBenefit.__table__.c.test_id == bindparam('test_id')),
                             benefits_dict)
```

How do you add multiple conditions in this case?

My  `benefits_dict`:

```
{'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@yahoo.com', 'id':12, 'test_id': 31},
   {'user_id': 1, 'email_address' : 'jack@msn.com', 'id':13, 'test_id': 31},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'www@www.org', 'id':14, 'test_id': 31},
   {'user_id': 2, 'email_address' : 'wendy@aol.com', 'id':15, 'test_id': 31}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either chain `where` clauses together or use the `and_` operator to add multiple conditions to your where clause (be sure to import the `and_` operator from `sqlalchemy.sql`). See [Conjunctions in the SQLAlchemy Expression Language Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions). For example:

```
# Using and_ operator
where(
    and_(
        table.c.id == 'id',
        table.c.name == 'name'
        )
    )

# chaining where clauses
where(table.c.id == 'id').\
where(table.c.name == 'name')
```